# I am trying to start a simple calculator program using notepad++, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

im pretty new to programming and coding, but I am trying to learn. With that I am trying to code a simple calculator on Notepad++ but I receive:
'notepad++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
heres the code

```
# Python code to demonstrate the working of  
# logical_and(), logical_or(), logical_xor() 
# and logical_invert() 

# importing "decimal" module to use decimal functions 
import decimal 

# Initializing decimal number 
a = decimal.Decimal(1000) 

# Initializing decimal number 
b = decimal.Decimal(1110) 

# printing logical_and of two numbers 
print ("The logical_and() of two numbers is : ",end="") 
print (a.logical_and(b)) 

# printing logical_or of two numbers 
print ("The logical_or() of two numbers is : ",end="") 
print (a.logical_or(b)) 

# printing exclusive or of two numbers 
print ("The exclusive or of two numbers is : ",end="") 
print (a.logical_xor(b)) 

# printing logical inversion of number 
print ("The logical inversion of number is : ",end="") 
print (a.logical_invert()) `
```

What am i doing wrong?
I am trying to run through command prompt, maybe that is the issue?

Comment: How are you trying to run this?

Comment: Notepad++ is a code editor, not a python interpreter. To run your code you have to make sure that installing Python on your machine and set the environmental variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ cannot be used as an interactive terminal for python. You should use input() to receive input while executing the script in a terminal.